# MySQL Permissions Necessary To Reset Password

Tags: mysql, security, permissions, user-defined-type

On my team there is a desire for some users to periodically update their MySQL password.

Our MySQL server is shared between a few projects (and certain users are assigned to certain projects). If I'm correct, changing your password requires access to the mysql.user table (which would, in turn allow the user to modify the password of any other user on the server.)

If this is all correct, is there any way to secure the database in a way that a user can update their password, but not other users?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A user should be able to change his/her own password strictly using [SET PASSWORD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-password.html).

For a connected user to set the new password to `mynewpass`, just run the following:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('mynewpass');
```

According to the [MySQL Documentation on *SET PASSWORD*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-password.html), if the server is a [**read-only enabled server**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_read_only), you need [**SUPER**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) privilege to do this. Otherwise, you can do this any time. There is no need for another user to set someone else's password. If you need a super user to set it you can still use SET PASSWORD.

To set the password of `'someuser'@'10.1.2.30'` to `hisnewpass`, run this:

```
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'someuser'@'10.1.2.30' = PASSWORD('hisnewpass');
```

According to the [MySQL Documentation on *SET PASSWORD*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-password.html), this is the equivalent of:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('hisnewpass')
WHERE User='someuser' AND Host='10.1.2.30';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Using [**SET PASSWORD**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-password.html) does not warrant manipulating `mysql.user`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set password for user like this:

```
 mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

OR using mysqladmin utility like:

```
shell> mysqladmin -u user_name -h host_name password "newpwd"
```

Basically, for a user to change password you need these GRANT options

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON *.* TO 'abc'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'mypass' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON `mysql`.`user` TO 'abc'@'%'
```

**Also, user should be able to change only his own password:**

I guess this is not handled in MySQL, infact root user only should give access to other users and he only should change their password if needs to be ..IMHO
technically in order to change password you need to access `mysql.user` table.